# How do I use the ConfigurableUI class in the IntelliJ plugin framework?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I've been browsing the intellij plugin documentation and cannot find a section where they explain how to build out the UI for configuring a plugin.

I notice they have a ConfigurableUI class [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/options/ConfigurableUi.java)

How would I go setting up this class to add a simple SwingUI component into my plugin?

I've done a search in their docs repository for the class and couldn't find anything: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sdk-docs

[image]

Ideally, I'd like a new menu item in "Tools" with my plugin name, and when I click on it, it spawns a JFrame/JPanel or something that I built in the .UI file builder in Intellij.

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://sites.google.com/site/malenkov/java/150403 for a reference of setting up configuration page. You can find plenty of implementations of Configurable in IntelliJ Community sources